# Why my sceneID doesn't work to download in landsat-utils?

Tags: python, landsat, download, usgs

I need to download Landsat images automatically in order to do a forest monitory. I'm using package landsat-utils. However, when I set my sceneID from my interest region the code doesn't work as I have expected.

So, here is one example of sceneID (LC82150682015350LGN01) which I would like to acquire to test my script.

I have tried to put my username and password from USGS however it doesn't fix the problem, but the problem hold on.

Here the code:

```
$ landsat download LC82150682015350LGN01

AttributeError: 'RemoteFileDoesntExist' object has no attribute 'message'
```

When I set my USGS username and password the error has been:

```
AttributeError: 'USGSError' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Why I am not get the file with this sceneID? I have changed it and I had the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the Collection 1 Landsat Product Identifier ([`LC08_L1TP_215068_20151216_20170331_01_T1`](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/metadata/12864/LC82150682015350LGN01/)) instead of the legacy [pre-collection Scene ID](https://landsat.usgs.gov/september-1-2017-countdown-landsat-pre-collection-datasets-removal)?

Comment: Yes. I put my usgs username and password however the program return me this masssage .USGSError: AUTH_UNAUTHORIZED: Forbidden - Approved role required for access to 'download' method.

Comment: I've read that I need a token autentication from USGS. Is there another information how can I acquire this token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to get Machine-to-Machine access to use third party libraries which are based on [this API](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/inventory/documentation). To get access you have to send request to USGS EROS User Services: `custserv@usgs.gov`

Here is required information to provide Machine-to-Machine access:

> To be considered for authorized access to data held in the USGS EROS
>   archives, we need to obtain some information from you. Please provide
>   details for each of the following. Upon receipt, I will forward your
>   request for review and consideration.
>
> 1) Your organization's primary purpose with regards to needing USGS
>   data. (How you will use the data you receive?)
>
> 2) EarthExplorer login Username (new users can register at
>   https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/register/)
>
> 3) Data set (s) required: Provide the EarthExplorer Data Set name(s) -
>   these can be found on EarthExplorer (NOTE: Landsat CDR data sets are
>   not eligible for this access)
>
> 4) Data product(s) required
>
> 5) Approximate number of scenes needed
>
> 6) Scripting capabilities: verify that PHP, PERL or another scripting
>   language is known to access the data
>
> 7) Detailed justification for needing this access
>
> 8) Complete name, address, and contact information for entity
>   requesting access

Comment: Ohhhh. Thank you so much. I've searched everything that I can and not find it anywhere. I will do what you advice me.

Comment: I have one doubt about fourth question: Is it about metadata of images? How for example the percentage of cloud or shadow?  If Yes, I have interest the images from Landsat 8 with all its metadata.

Comment: @DiogoCaribé As I understand they ask about `Data Type L-1` parameter. Here is metadata parameters description: https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/DD/landsat_dictionary.html#data_type_l1